# print cells type in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array like:

```
>>text

'Sentence1'
'Sentence2'
'Sentence3'
```

Whenever I use

```
sprintf(fid,'%s\n',text)
```

I get an error saying:

```
'Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.'
```

But if I put :

```
sprintf(fid,'%s\n',char(text))
```

It works but in the file appears all the sentences mixed all together like with no sense.

Can you recommend me what to do?

Whener I put text I get:

```
>>text
'Title '
'Author'
'comments '
{3x1} cell
```

That is why I can not use text{:}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you issue

```
sprintf('%s\n', text)
```

you are saying "print a string with a newline. The string is this cell array". That's not correct; a cell-array is not a string.

If you issue

```
sprintf('%s\n', char(text))
```

you are saying "print a string with a newline. The string is this cell array, which I convert to character array.". The thing is, that conversion results in a *single* character array, and `sprintf` will re-use the `%s\n` format only for *multiple* inputs. Moreover, it writes that single character array *by column*, meaning, all characters in the first column, concatenated horizontally with all characters from the second column, concatenated with all characters from the third column, etc.

Therefore, the approprate call to `sprintf` is something with *multiple* inputs:

```
sprintf(fid, '%s\n', text{:})
```

because the cell-expansion `text{:}` creates a comma-separated list from all entries in the cell-array, which is exactly what `sprintf`/`fprintf` expects.

**EDIT**  As you indicate:, you have non-char entries in `text`. You have to check for that. If you want to pass only the strings into `fprintf`, use

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', text{ cellfun('isclass', text, 'char') })
```

if that `{3x1 cell}` is *again* a set of strings, so you want to write all strings *recursively*, then just use something like this:

```
function textWriter 

    text = {...
        'Title'
        'Author'
        'comments'
        {...
            'Title2'
            'Author2'
            'comments2'
            {...
                'Title3'
                'Author3'
                'comments3'
            }
        }
    }

    text = cell2str(text);
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', text{:});


end


function out = cell2str(c)

    out = {};
    for ii = c(:)'
        if iscell(ii{1})
            S = cell2str(ii{1});
            out(end+1:end+numel(S)) = S;
        else
            out{end+1} = ii{1};
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: No cause whenever I do it is says:
'Inputs must be character arrays.'

Comment: @R_user: well, you are trying to use `sprintf` to write to a file with ID `fid`...this is incorrect, because that is what `fprintf` is for. `sprintf` is for (re-)formatting strings. Also, are *all* the entries in `text` character arrays, or are there other types in there as well? If `text` is relatively small, you can try `cellplot(text)`.

Comment: @R_user: also, I can only produce that error if I issue `char(text)`...At least in R2010a, that error is not an issue with `f`/`sprintf` but with how you use `char`. But you don't have to use `char`; see my answer.